# How to create bag file?

Tags: ros, bag

I use ros and sample `.bag` files. I try to create my own `.bag` file from my images or video data. How can I do it?

[This guide](https://cse.sc.edu/~jokane/agitr/agitr-letter-bag.pdf) says has a topic named **"Recording and replaying bag files**
**"** But it doesn't use images.

Comment: Do you already publish your image data on a ROS topic? If yes, use `rosbag record` with other arguments as advised in the document you link. It does not matter what type the messages on the topic are, as long as you provide the correct topic name.

Comment: oh, no I didin't it.

Answer (score 5):

As mikkola said in his comment you need to publish your images to a topic. Once your images are being published, the `rosbag record -O mybackfile.bag image-topic-name` will record the images too.

If you are not publishing the images then you need to write an image publisher. In order to do that you must load each images with OpenCV, convert it to `sensor_msgs::ImagePtr` and send it via `image_transport::Publisher`. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages) is a full example of an image publisher.